# WebMatrix Alternative for SqlCommand.Parameters.Add

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I've used WebMatrix for parameterized query like:

```
string sql = @"SELECT col FROM table WHERE id = @0 AND name = @1";
db.Query(sql, someID, someName);
```

But I got stuck on unknown count of parameters. In traditional ADO.NET solution we have `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` so we can add parameters one by one programmatically.

Is there any alternative like `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` in WebMatrix?

Comment: Can't you supply it with an array of objects as the second parameter?

Comment: @rene Yes you're right.. I found the solution myself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

OK.. I found the solution myself in [this blog post](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/156/webmatrix-database-helpers-for-in-clauses). The key point is *Database.Query() method accepts an array of Objects.*

So given an array of parameters and properly construct the SQL string would do the work.